# iOS - Passing LaunchOptions to a sub-method

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

Im trying to add an asyncronous lookup for Push Notifications and I'm having a problem passing launchOptions to the*`@selector`. Can you please tell me what I need to change?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    /* Operation Queue init (autorelease) */

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

    /* Create  NSInvocationOperation to call loadDataWithOperation, passing in nil */
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setupPushNotifications) object:launchOptions];

    [queue addOperation:operation];     /* Add the operation to the queue */

    [operation release];
}
```

and

```
-(void)setupPushNotifications:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  
{
    //Init Airship launch options
    NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];


    // Create Airship singleton that's used to talk to Urban Airship servers.
    // Please populate AirshipConfig.plist with your info from http://go.urbanairship.com
    [UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

    NSLog(@"Registering for Notifications");    
    // Register for notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong. You forgot to include the colon, `@selector(setupPushNotifications:)`. The colon indicates that there is an argument being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setupPushNotifications) object:launchOptions];
```

to

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setupPushNotifications:) object:launchOptions];
```